# migrating from gforge to teamforge

Tags: repository

can anyone give an detailed procedure on how to
migrate projects from gforge version(4.5) to teamforge version 5.2.0. 
Migration includes source repository, bug tracking, wiki and discussions.
is it possible to shift all of them.

What's the best way to handle a situation like this?

Thank
You

Answer (score 0):

Teamforge uses Subversion, so assuming you have commandline access to the server then you can use the [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) commands.
You will need to run these commands for each repository.

Some (I don't know which) of the pages and wiki are also stored in subversion repositories, so you may be able to migrate that using the same method.